# See also part from a json format of a wikipedia page

Tags: python, json, wikipedia-api

I want to access the **"See also"** section in the Wikipedia page which is in a json format.
Is there a way to do it using Wikipedia API?
Or is there any other way to do this?
Here is the code I've written so far

```
import wikipediaapi
wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
page_py = wiki_wiki.page('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=SMALL&prop=revisions&rvprop=content')
resp = requests.get(page_py)
data = resp.json()
```

THe json file of that link is as given below

```
{"batchcomplete":"","warnings":{"main":{"*":"Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at <https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce> for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes. Use [[Special:ApiFeatureUsage]] to see usage of deprecated features by your application."},"revisions":{"*":"Because \"rvslots\" was not specified, a legacy format has been used for the output. This format is deprecated, and in the future the new format will always be used."}},"query":{"pages":{"1808130":{"pageid":1808130,"ns":0,"title":"SMALL","revisions":[{"contentformat":"text/x-wiki","contentmodel":"wikitext","*":"{{Infobox programming language\n| name = Small Machine Algol Like Language\n| logo = <!-- Filename only -->\n| logo caption = \n| screenshot = <!-- Filename only -->\n| screenshot caption = \n| paradigms = [[Procedural programming|Procedural]], [[Imperative programming|imperative]], [[Structured programming|structured]], [[Object-oriented programming|object-oriented]]\n| family = [[ALGOL]]\n| designer = Nevil Brownlee\n| developer = [[University of Auckland]]\n| released = {{Start date and age|1980}}<!-- If known, add |mm|dd|df=yes -->\n| latest release version = Final\n| latest release date = {{Start date and age|1985}}<!-- If known, add |mm|dd|df=yes -->\n| typing = \n| scope = \n| programming language = [[Fortran]] IV, SMALL\n| discontinued = Yes\n| platform = [[Mainframe computer|Mainframe]]s: [[Burroughs Corporation|Burroughs]] B6700, [[Digital Equipment Corporation|DEC]] [[PDP-10]]\n| operating system = [[TOPS-10]], VM/[[Conversational Monitor System|CMS]]\n| license = \n| file ext = \n| file format = <!-- or: | file formats = -->\n| website = <!-- {{URL|www.example.com}} -->\n| implementations = \n| dialects = \n| influenced by = [[ALGOL]]\n| influenced = \n}}\n'''Small Machine Algol Like Language''' ('''SMALL'''), is a [[computer programming]] [[programming language|language]] developed by Dr. Nevil Brownlee of the [[University of Auckland]].\n\n==History==\nThe aim of the language was to enable writing [[ALGOL]]-like code that ran on a small machine. It also included the <code>string</code> [[data type]] for easier text manipulation.\n\nSMALL was used extensively from about 1980 to 1985 at Auckland University as a programming teaching aid, and for some internal projects. Originally, it was written in [[Fortran]] IV, to run on a [[Burroughs Corporation]] B6700 [[mainframe computer]]. Subsequently, it was rewritten in SMALL, and ported to a [[Digital Equipment Corporation]] (DEC) [[PDP-10]] mainframe (on the [[operating system]] [[TOPS-10]]) and an IBM S360 mainframe (on the operating system VM [[Conversational Monitor System]] (VM/CMS)).\n\nAbout 1985, SMALL had some [[object-oriented programming]] features added to handle structures (that were missing from the early language), and to formalise file manipulation operations.\n\n==See also==\n*[[Lua (programming language)]]\n*[[Squirrel (programming language)]]\n\n==References==\n{{Reflist}}\n\n==External links==\n*[https://www.caida.org/home/staff/nevil/ Nevil Brownlee staff page, Center for Applied Internet Data Analysis]\n*[https://www.caida.org/~nevil/ Nevil Brownlee personal page, Center for Applied Internet Data Analysis]\n\n{{ALGOL programming}}\n\n[[Category:Algol programming language family]]\n[[Category:Systems programming languages]]\n[[Category:Procedural programming languages]]\n[[Category:Object-oriented programming languages]]\n[[Category:Programming languages created in 1980]]"}]}}}
```

The see also part should be in the form of links that are clickable in the ouput

Comment: what did you try? if you start checking it manually step by step then you finally create correct path to get it. You could use `type()` to check if you get list or dict and use `[number]` when you get list and check `.keys()` when you get dict. Start with `print( type(data) )` and `print( data.keys() )`

Comment: clickable links you may have only if you generate HTML and open it in web browser. Only some consoles may have function to treat links as clickable but you can't force it.

Comment: it would be simpler to search path in `data` if you would use `json.dums(data, indents=2)` to create text with indentations - you will see which values you have to use with `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `requests.get()` and `'http://en.wikipedia.org/ ...` you get it as `JSON data` which needs a lot of code to parse data and get `See also`.

Using `wiki_wiki.page('SMALL')` you can get it as special object which have all data parsed and it gives easy access to sections like `See more`.

```
import wikipediaapi

wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
page_py = wiki_wiki.page('SMALL')

see_also = page_py.section_by_title("See also")

see_also_links = see_also.text.split('\n')
print('See also:', see_also_links, '\n')

for link in see_also_links:
    page = wiki_wiki.page(link)
    print('--- title:', page.title, '---')
    print(page.summary, '\n')
```

This gives me links from `See also` which I can use to load next pages

```
See also: ['Lua (programming language)', 'Squirrel (programming language)']

--- title: Lua (programming language) ---
Lua ( LOO-ə; from Portuguese: lua [ˈlu.(w)ɐ] meaning moon) is a lightweight, high-level, multi-paradigm programming language designed primarily for embedded use in applications. Lua is cross-platform, since the interpreter of compiled bytecode is written in ANSI C, and Lua has a relatively simple C API to embed it into applications.Lua was originally designed in 1993 as a language for extending software applications to meet the increasing demand for customization at the time. It provided the basic facilities of most procedural programming languages, but more complicated or domain-specific features were not included; rather, it included mechanisms for extending the language, allowing programmers to implement such features. As Lua was intended to be a general embeddable extension language, the designers of Lua focused on improving its speed, portability, extensibility, and ease-of-use in development.

--- title: Squirrel (programming language) ---
Squirrel is a high level imperative, object-oriented programming language, designed to be a lightweight scripting language that fits in the size, memory bandwidth, and real-time requirements of applications like video games and embedded systems.
MirthKit, a simple toolkit for making and distributing open source, cross-platform 2D games, uses Squirrel for its platform. It is used extensively by Code::Blocks for scripting and was also used in Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles: My Life as a King. It is also used in Left 4 Dead 2, Portal 2 and Thimbleweed Park for scripted events and in NewDark, an unofficial Thief 2: The Metal Age engine update, to facilitate additional, simplified means of scripting mission events, aside of the regular C scripting.
```